# Removing duplicates from MySQL on a column that's too big to INDEX

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I'm trying to remove duplicate rows from a table with millions of rows.  The field I want to check for duplicates on is too long (it's storing URLs) to put a `UNIQUE` index on.  Is there any way to remove duplicates quickly?

The recommended method for removing duplicates:

```
DELETE t1 FROM table1 AS t1 JOIN table1 AS t2 ON t1.id>t2.id AND t1.name=t2.name;
```

Never seems to finish its job, though I suppose it might just require a lot of time to do.

One idea I've heard here is to create an `MD5` hash column for indexing and comparison.  Is this the recommended route?  If so, should I be truncating this column for space/speed considerations?

Comment: I would have thought that creating a partial (prefix) index on name would make that query run a lot quicker.

Comment: Some recommendations at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088447/slow-self-join-delete-query

Comment: @Frederick but these are URLS, so using partial comparisons may be wrong for comparison?  e.g. google.com vs google.com/page

Comment: The db won't be able to purely use the index but jt should be able to use the index to greatly reduce the number of rows where it does actually have to do the comparison

Comment: @FrederickCheung: I'm curious: how do you create a "prefix index" in MySQL?

Comment: Pass a length to create index : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Answer (score 0):

The hash would give you a column you could put and index on so then t1.Name = t2.Name would be a far less expensive t1.Hash = t2.Hash.
Adding the hash to 1,000,000 records would take a while though.

Another option if this is a one off would be to page the clear out e.g. something like

```
Where T1 >= 0 and T1 < 10000
Where T1 >= 10001 and T1 < 20000
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I may not have thought this through, but it's worth a try:

- Create a column, `md5url`, and fill it with the md5 of the url (`UPDATE table1 SET md5url = MD5(url)`
- Make a (non-unique) index on that column `md5url` - md5 should be short enough to do so
- change your statement to:

  ```
  DELETE t1 
  FROM table1 AS t1 
       JOIN table1 AS t2 
            ON t1.md5url = t2.md5url 
               AND t1.name=t2.name 
               AND t1.id>t2.id;
  ```

That way, the JOIN condition works primarily on an index. If that indexed column, md5url, fits, then we actually check the URL - because, depending on how many urls you have, it becomes possible at some point, that two URLs *may* have the same MD5. The third condition is clear - ensuring that only one of the two identical columns is deleted.

I would love to hear whether this works - it makes perfect sense in my head right now ;-)

Comment: It did work, but I can't say whether it went any faster than it would have w/o md5.. since it took like a whole day.  Also, I wonder whether your approach actually saved time-- question is whether MySQL evaluated in a "lazy" way.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747047/is-mysql-logic-evaluation-lazy-short-circuiting-in-join-clause and lemme know what you think